# Is it possible to plot 3D bars on a 3D digital elevation model that has either another raster layer or polygon overlaying it?

Tags: qgis, r, blendergis

I am trying to plot point data on top of a DEM that has another layer on top (either another raster or polygon). I want the whole plot to be in 3D, so the DEM for elevation, the layer on top for color, and the point data as bars where the height represents their value. Would this be possible for example in R?

For now I have the DEM file and another raster/polygon on top of it figure out, but I do not know how to add the 3D bars. [image]